# Using browser.title to confirm EXACT text

Tags: browser, watir, title

I want to confirm the exact text that appears on the browser tab.

Using "#{browser.title.include? 'Awards'} Awards tab titled 'Awards'" only confirms that the word 'Awards' appears in the browser title.

Is there a browser.title.exact? (or something similar) I can use to confirm that ONLY the word 'Awards' is the ONLY word in the browser title?

Answer (score 0):

`browser.title` simply returns a [string](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html). To do an exact match use the `==` operator:

```
browser.title == 'Awards'
```

If you want it more methody looking, you can also do:

```
browser.title.eql?('Awards')
```